# Microsoft .NET HTTP handling differently with defaultsystemproxy

Tags: c#, .net, http, ssis, proxy

I encountered a very strange problem. I have an SSIS job which is running a C# code on .NET 4.0. The job is posting and requesting data from an API endpoint using HTTP.
Everything was fine for quite some time but a few days ago the SSIS job slowed down rapidly.

After long hours of investigation I found a strange workaround:

When I open:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\machine.conf
```

and I add to this the config this section:

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy>
    <proxy
      usesystemdefault = "true"
    />
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

and I restart the SSIS service. Then the SSIS job is running fast like charm.

We have a proxy set in winhttp module with bypass list. However the bypass list contains the destination URLs which the SSIS job is calling so it doesn't matter anyway. I tried to remove winhttp proxy configuration and the behavior was the same.

I even tried to change/remove Internet Settings proxy configuration but behavior is the same. I even tried to manipulate registry for InternetSettings (proxy) under domain service accounts which are used for SSIS and DTexec.exe but nothing helped.

The only thing what is working for now is to add the section to the machine.conf and restart the SSIS service.

I checked the C# code and there is almost nothing about proxy except:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true"/>
    <settings>
      <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false"/>
    </settings>
  </system.net>
```

Can someone explain me what is happening on my server and why is the system.net section in the machine.conf working like a magic trick?
It's not the server issue. We have this service running in a cluster so I swapped also SSIS to another node and the behavior is the same.

I checked Wireshark and Firewall logs but there is no sign of any proxy communication.

The LAN has WPAD configuration enabled so the only thing what is on my mind now is this:
The 'usesystemdefault = "true"' is somehow able to query WPAD configuration from LAN and then this configuration is used for SSIS job when initiating HTTP connections to the API endpoint. When I remove the 'usesystemdefault = "true"' section of the .NET, then SSIS job is not acquiring WPAD config and the communication is going directly over the network. This makes some sense to me however I am still not able to query any communication to proxy servers defined in WPAD with or without the 'usesystemdefault = "true"' block active in machine.conf.

Can someone help me please understand what is happenning and why 'usesystemdefault = "true"' in machine.conf is like a magic statement?